# Load AppConfig with binding redirects from resource

Tags: c#

I have a .NET Framework 4.6.2 application `myApp.exe` with several internal and external dependencies. All dependencies are included into the main application `myApp.exe` as resources.

On application startup, our custom assembly loader gets notified via the event [`AssemblyResolve`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve?view=netcore-3.1) and loads the requested assembly from `myApp.exe`'s resources via [`GetManifestResourceStream()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices._assembly.getmanifestresourcestream?view=netframework-4.8) and [`Assembly.Load()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.load?view=netcore-3.1#System_Reflection_Assembly_Load_System_Byte___).

This works fine, except `App.config`: the resources contain `myApp.App.config`, but the custom assembly loader is not loading it yet. This leads to a problem because all the assembly binding redirects specified in `App.config` are not applied by the .NET Runtime. When placing `myApp.exe.config` beside `myApp.exe` (as usual in .NET), everything is working fine.

I'm trying to find a way to avoid the additional file `myApp.exe.config`. Instead, I want to load the app config (especially the binding redirects) from the resources as well. Is that even possible? If yes, how can I do so?

Comment: How did you include and load `App.config` file?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski What exactly do you mean? `App.config` is not loaded - that is the challenge to solve. But it is embedded as a resource.

Comment: I had to reread the question. Why do you need binding redirects when you have correct dlls embedded?

Comment: @Jacek: due to dependency hell: we're referencing and embedding `System.Net.Http` in a different version than in GAC. This crashes at runtime. Adding a binding redirect via `myApp.exe.config` solves the problem.

Comment: I suppose you embed the correct `System.Net.Http` inside? Did you try this?https://blog.slaks.net/2013-12-25/redirecting-assembly-loads-at-runtime

Comment: We're facing exactly the issue as described in your link: since the assembly with the wrong version is found in the GAC, the `AssemblyResolve` event is not fired and therefore our custom assembly loader cannot do its work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly, you can't tell CLR which file you want to load as a runtime config. Runtime looks up for xml configuration in following order:

1. application config
2. machine config

The lookup is performed every time when CLR needs info from config, for example binding redirects and assembly locations on assembly load.

It is mostly a part of assembly loading process and it is better to leave as is. You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies

Edit: However, you can live without config file. You said you have all your assemblies embedded into exe assembly and you load everything via custom resolver. Note that your custom assembly resolver is called only when standard resolve pipeline fails to load an assembly. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26673659/2811109

Comment: Thank you! Frankly, I was expecting your answer.